# How to make tagged UITextField like in Mail app address filed?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to build custom searchBar. And I want to support searching by tags. When user select some tag-filter, I need to add it in my searchBar which is `UITextField` by inserting a colored rectangle with filter text like Apple Mail or Messages app inserts contact names. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: 
https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenField

it's exactly for what you're looking for.